# Should the repair tag be broken up into two categories

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

So people are using [repair](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repair) in question which is fine. Could there be a potential confusion issue?

I would think there is a difference between

1. Repair damage/imperfection to wood: [How can I repair a split in a board?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/889/how-can-i-repair-a-split-in-a-board)
2. Fixing broken equipment: [What could cause a lathe to have low torque and only develop approximately half its rated RPM?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/660/what-could-cause-a-lathe-to-have-low-torque-and-only-develop-approximately-half/689#689)

Do we only use [repair](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repair) for the first example and maybe retag the second as [maintenance](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance)? Or does the potential perceived ambiguity even exist?

Answer (score 3):

I would lean towards (but I'm not 100% there) having four tags, two for wood ([wood-repair](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood-repair) [wood-maintenance](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood-maintenance)) and two for tools [tool-repair](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-repair) ([tool-maintenance](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-maintenance)).

[wood-repair](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood-repair): Used for questions like your first example "How can I repair a split in a board"

[wood-maintenance](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood-maintenance): long term care of a finished product. Probably replacing the dumb [long-term-care](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-term-care) tag that I created. Used for questions about how often they should refinish something, should it not be placed in sunlight, etc.

[tool-repair](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-repair): Fixing *broken* equipment

[tool-maintenance](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-maintenance): Maintaining equipment in good working order. Oiling, sharpening, aligning, storing, etc.

It's possible this is too fine-grained but this is the first solution that came to mind and at least it puts every concept in a nice spot. On the other hand, [wood-maintenance](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wood-maintenance) is not a term someone would think of when wondering about how to care for their finished product. There's probably a better name for this.

Comment: i think that if we split them up now might be better. Let say that `wood-maintenance` ends up being a dud. Easy to retire that tag instead of going through a bunch of repair tags later to scrub. `wood-maintenance` does seem odd. A synonym might help.. not sure what it could be either.

Comment: wood-care could also be a good fit.

Comment: I like it.   Make it so!  ;)

Comment: Cleaned up existing questions user `repair`. I wasnt sure about http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/660/what-could-cause-a-lathe-to-have-low-torque-and-only-develop-approximately-half since the tool was functioning... just not well. It could go either way.

Comment: I agree that tool repair and tool maintenance should be separate. Wood repair and wood maintenance are descriptive but seem like awkward names.

Comment: None of us appear to be hot about `wood-maintenance` but `wood-repair` is a little better. Unless we want to come from the other direction and call it `wood-damage`

Comment: FWIW google seems to favour `wood-care` and in places that `wood-maintenance` is mentioned it is partnered with care. So one could be a synonym of the other for sure.

Comment: I updated your question [here](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/621/what-can-i-do-to-help-keep-walnut-from-fading-over-time). Wood care does not _have_ to be long term. Feel free to change it if you think of something better.

Comment: Originally I thought 2 and then 4 different tags was going overboard, but now I'm even considering  multiple classes of wood repair--you can either fix/stabilize/work around existing defects that were present in the rough lumber, you can fix your own mistakes, or you can repair damage that occurred over time.

Comment: @rob I am definitely in the boat of lets make more now.... later coming back to remove one or two tags is easier then trying to comb through wood-repair and reclassify then all

Comment: @Matt I agree!!